# Me sale el siguiente error en JavaScript: VM72:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')

Tags: javascript, html

Me sale el error VM72:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value') en js, el código funciona pero me aparece este error y no me deja poner más cosas despues del value:

```js
 $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        let radiobtn = $('input[type=radio]');
        let checkeados = $('#califradio:checked').length;
        let contados = radiobtn.length;
        contados = contados / 3;
        let porcentaje = checkeados / contados;
        porcentaje = porcentaje * 100;

        var inputs = $('input[name^=porcentaje]');
        var count = inputs.length;
        for (let x = 0; x <= count; x++) {
            document.getElementsByName("porcentaje")[x].value = porcentaje;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un array tiene un largo y tiene índices. El primer indice es 0 y el último es `largo - 1` (ya que se comienza a contar desde cero)

Cuando haces :

```
for (let x = 0; x <= count; x++)
```

Estas iterando desde cero hasta el `largo`, por lo que hay un ultimo elemento que no existe, es decir `undefined`, debes reemplazar el `<=` por `<`

```
for (let x = 0; x < count; x++)
```

Otra manera es, reemplazar esto:

```
var inputs = $('input[name^=porcentaje]');
var count = inputs.length;
for (let x = 0; x <= count; x++) {
  document.getElementsByName("porcentaje")[x].value = porcentaje;
```

Por esto:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=porcentaje]').forEach(e=> e.value=porcentaje);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso solucionó mi problema